# summarize data with NAs using ddply function

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am trying to summarize data with NA values and am using the ddply function.

For example, using the data included below,

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), 100),
        ValOne = sample(c(1, 0, NA), replace = T, 300),
        ValTwo = sample(c(1,NA), replace = T, 300),
        VarThree = sample(c("Thanks", "alot"), replace = T, 300))

> head(dat)
  IndID ValOne ValTwo
1   AAA      1     NA
2   BBB     NA      1
3   CCC      0     NA
4   AAA     NA     NA
5   BBB     NA     NA
6   CCC      1      1
```

I want to calculate the number of times that each individual has a 1 in the ValOne and ValTwo column  I am using the code below to create a new `data.frame` and summarize the data by IndID and use both `length` and `sum` functions.

```
library(plyr)
tbl <- ddply(dat, "IndID", summarise, 
    ColOne = length(dat$ValOne[dat$ColOne == 1]),
    NumHighHDOP = sum(dat$ValTwo[dat$ValTwo == 1], na.rm = T))
```

As seen below,

```
 IndID ColOne NumHighHDOP
1   AAA      0         155
2   BBB      0         155
3   CCC      0         155
```

the resulting table summarizes the data for the entire `data.frame` and not for each individual.

Both approaches (`length` and `sum`) are struggling with the NAs in the `data.frame.`  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT** With the new data set including a factor.  Is it also possible to calculate the number of "Thanks" for each individual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  We group by 'IndID', and get the count of 1 for each column with `summarise_each`.  To remove the `NA` elements, either `na.omit` or use a logical condition to output `TRUE` only for 1.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   group_by(IndID) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(sum(.==1 & !is.na(.))))
   #or
   #summarise_each(funs(sum(na.omit(.)==1)))
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset in the OP's post, if we want to count the 'Thanks' in the third column, we can use `%in%` (assuming that 'Thanks' is not present in the other two columns and 1 not in the last column).

```
dat %>% 
   group_by(IndID) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum(na.omit(.) %in% c(1, 'Thanks'))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  looks like your code is specific to numeric values.  Is it possible to summarize a factor as specified in the EDIT above?

Comment: Yea, your post got me thinking through different applications, thus the addition. Thanks for both the answers.